# Different path to same routing file from main routing file in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, caching, routes

I have 7 bundles in my project. So I pointed each from main routing file (app->config->routing.yml).

I have a requirement that same routing file inside a bundle can able to be called using different paths. Like one path with an argument and other without argument.

My main routing file looks like as follows

```
clubadmin_general:
    resource: "@TestGeneralBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    host:     "mywebsite"
    prefix:   /{url_identifier}/admin/

clubadmin_general_club_domain:
    resource: "@TestGeneralBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /admin/
```

The routing file inside the bundle is common when called form main routing file. The routing file inside the bundle is looks like..

```
show_dashboard:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: TestGeneralBundle:Dashboard:index }
```

When I called, routing defined first gives "No route found". But the second works well. When I changed the order, always second works well.

In the above code  path "**/admin/**" works well. But path "**/{url_identifier}/admin/**" will not work.

I think "**show_dashboard**" name is cached for a route. May be that is the issue. But couldn't find a solution.

Someone please help me.

Comment: The problem is that show_dashboard is not impacted by the prefix so the latest route named show_dashboard overwrites any previous ones.  I don't know of any straight forward way to work around it. bin/console debug:route will make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution... By create different environment, the cache folder get separated and then can able to use same routing names with different paths.